# Discord file closing warning

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Can anyone share any information on this or show me how to resolve this problem I've been trying to figure this out myself but I'm not too sure on how to fix this warning or even to ignore it myself.  What this code should be doing is to take every file within the folder and add it to a discord forum thread by creating a new thread for every file but when I try to do that I get a warning about closing file descriptor 3 on garbage collection

```js
const { Client, Discord, GatewayIntentBits,  } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildModeration,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.AutoModerationConfiguration,
  ]
})
//const thread = '1099921205324173332'; // Replace with your channel ID

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
  // Check if the message author is the bot
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  // Check if the message contains the !upload command
  if (message.content.startsWith('!upload')) {
    // Get the directory path from the message content
    const dirPath = message.content.split(' ')[1];
    thread = "1099921205324173332";
    // Check if the directory exists
    if (fs.open(dirPath) && fs.lstat(dirPath)) {
      
      // The directory exists, so read all the files in the directory
      const fileNames = fs.readdir(dirPath);

      // Loop through each file and upload it to the channel
      for (let fileName of Object.values(fileNames)) {
        
       // const filePath = `${dirPath}/${fileName}`;
      //  const buffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
        GuildForumMessageRequired = 'GuildForumMessageRequired'
       {
      const threadChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'test');      
      threadChannel.threads.create({
        name: fileName.name,
        autoArchiveDuration: 60,
        type: 'GUILD_PUBLIC_THREAD',
         message: {
          content: `New thread created with file:` ,//"${fileName.name.replace('/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, ""')}!`,
          files: [fileName]
          },
     
      })}
        console.log(`Uploaded ${fileName} to ${message.channel.name}`);
      }
    }
     else 
     {
      // If the directory doesn't exist, send an error message
      message.reply('The specified directory does not exist.');
    }
  console.log(`Created thread: ${thread.name}`);
  }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This warning is appearing because you are opening a file using `fs.open()` and not closing it
this is happening on the condition :

```js
if (fs.open(dirPath) && fs.lstat(dirPath))
```

to fix this you should close the file, either with a callback function:

```js
if (fs.open(dirPath , (err, fileDescriptor) => fs.close(fileDescriptor , callback) && fs.lstat(dirPath)) {
```

or storing the returned value (the file descriptor) in a variable then closing it:

```js
let fd = fs.open(dirPath)
if (fd && fs.lstat(dirPath)) {
//code
}
fs.close(fd)
```

however here in your case you shouldn't be using the `fs.open` you can use `fs. existsSync()` to check if a file or a directory exits

Comment: It was more because I wanted to try open intead of exists as I had a different error and was given no info on how or where to see how I can improve my code I will try to see if this helps my problem thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: np, don't hesitate to ask again in case of any error or problem